# How to apply cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps to false in Alfresco 4.2.4

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

Hi and thanks in advance for the help

I have aproblem that when i change a property in Alfresco, the document is versioned to a minor version on Alfresco 4.2.3.3

So if i upload a document to Alfresco via CMIS (create document 1.0) and after taht modifiy a property i get the version 1.1 i would like to keep the 1.0 version with the modified property. Only want to version if the content is changed.

**What i have done so far**

Set the value of the property cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps in a just created document. I have done this diferent options:

1. Try to set the value of the property cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps. It says the property doesnt exist, may be is in the aspect cm:versionable?
2. Add the aspect cm:versionable, for CMIS it doesnt exist *Type 'P:cm:versionable' is unknown!*
3. Tried with cmis:versionable: but CMIS keep saying *Type 'P:cmis:versionable' is unknown!*

This errors are when calling to Session.getTypeDefinition sending P:cm:versionable and false. or P:cmis:versionable and false to the method.

I have a custom Type that i can modifiy, but i dont know how to change it so it overrides the value of that property. Is it possible?

**Not an option**

I cannot change the contentModel.xml to set by default the property cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps to false inside the aspect cm:versionable because other documents that use the aspect need to work with that property true.

**Questions**

---

**Is there a way to override a value of a property only for some types?**

**Can i via CMIS 1.1 set the value of the property cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps someway?**

**Any other option to avoid the behavior?**

---

Enviroment:

- Alfresco 4.2.3.3
- On Tomcat 7.0.53
- Code in java with CMIS 1.1 and apache openCMIS 0.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No CMIS doesn't see the **cm:versionable** aspect or it's properties. I'm not sure if that's a bug or not, but we solved it by a Site Rule which sets the **cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps** to false (uncheck the checkbox).

You can also write a JavaScript which triggers on the rule of write a behaviour. But our CMIS application only writes to 1 site, so it was easier to create a rule for it.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer. Ok, the main approaches will be to use a rule or behaviour to set the value, and override what CMIS set. If i want this to happen to every document i add to Alfresco (either it enters via CMIS, or share) which option would you take?

Comment: I'd add an extra value that it has been set by CMIS, so you can check on that value.

Comment: Great idea, that way i can check if it has been executed and check the "state". Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can override propery using override tag in your custom content model.

```
 <type name="custom:contenttype">
            <parent>cm:content</parent>
            <properties>                   
            </properties>
            <overrides>
                <property name="cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps">
                    <default>(Put your value here)</default>
                </property>                 
            </overrides>             
        </type>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. In this scenario, if i override the property, will CMIS override my value when setting the versionable aspect?, cause in CMIS all the documents are versionable and i cant be sure if CMIS will "override" my "overriden" value.

Comment: When you apply that aspect to node using CMIS then only this property will be avilable and this overrides will set default value which is mentioned in the xml file.

Comment: hi, yes but it looks like, when i use this approach, CMIS override again the value, cause when it calls Alfresco, seems to set the value and dont use the default, Alfresco use the value set by CMIS. or it seems like it.